Blazor is encoding a plus in my razor page
Google reads structured data from a web page. This is in the form:
<script type="application/ld+json">
    @StructuredData
</script>

And the @StructuredData getter must be populated in the pre-render call to OnInitializedAsync(). And this all works great except for one thing.
While the final page does show:
<script type="application/ld+json">
    @StructuredData
</script>

The page is displayed in Google's test as:
<script type="application/ld&#x2B;json">
    @StructuredData
</script>

And because of that, Google does not find the data. My guess is that the pre-render pass encodes the + for some reason and the final pass does not. But maybe it's something else.
Any idea what is going on? And more important, how I can fix it?

ASP.NET Core is very aggressive w.r.t. HTML-encoding anything that ever stood within smelling-distance of an angle-bracket - and there are still open issues about it. (that said, &#x2B; is semantically identical to + - so the real bug here is Google's spider) - but anyway, I might suggest you try this: <script type="@this.Html.Raw( "application/ld+json" )"> and see what happens.

Out of curiosity, is your @StructuredData expression also (excessively?) HTML-encoded, or is HTML-encoding acceptable there?

@Dai The content of the script is a JSON object. So it's <script type="application/ld+json">{ /* JSON properties */ </script>. I've moved the <script> part inside the MarkupString - I'll be able to see in 10 minutes if that solves it. If not, my syntax in the web page may be wrong. thanks

I don't know why this makes a difference. And I wish I understood what is going on here. But this fixes it. I had:
<script type="application/ld+json">
    @StructuredData
</script>

I changed it to:
@StructuredData

where I moved the <script> part inside the @StructuredData property which returns a MarkupString.
I understand why putting everything inside the MarkupString means that will all be written out literally. What I don't understand is why Blazor converted the + in the page returned to Google on the pre-render pass, but it is a literal + on the final render.
But a solution gets the job done.
